# laravel eloquent relationship with and where clause based on foreign column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi I want to retrieve my `projects` held in a db which are owned by an auth `user` who  also creates `clients` (they have many projects and tasks) and `tasks` (belongs to a project and tasks and user).

I want to retrieve all tasks that are not marked as closed in the status table, I know the id of this is 2 and I can retrieve this as so:

```
public function getOpenProjects() {

    return \Project::with(['clients', 'tasks', 'status'])
        ->where('status_id', '!=', '2')
        ->whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)
        ->get();
}
```

But how can I change this to query against a column in the statuses table, i.e. the name column in that table?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$value = 'someName';
Project::with(['clients', 'tasks', 'status' => function($q) use($value) {
    // Query the name field in status table
    $q->where('name', '=', $value); // '=' is optional
}])
->where('status_id', '!=', '2')
->whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)
->get();
```

Also you may try this (It will fetch records only if the `query` returns `name` you want, otherwise none):

```
$value = 'someName';
Project::with(['clients', 'tasks', 'status'])
       ->whereHas('status', function($q) use($value) {
       // Query the name field in status table
       $q->where('name', '=', $value); // '=' is optional
})
->where('status_id', '!=', '2')
->whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)
->get();
```

Comment: I want to query the status table name field not the projects table

Comment: Yes, that's it `$q->where('name', '=', $value)` inside the `closure` which is the value of `status`.

Comment: why does it fetch status with null?

Comment: Do you have a `select` statement ? It's probably you don't have any status with that name.

Comment: I do though, take this for example project has a project_name of Open but is still retrieved: {"id": "115","user_id": "1","client_id": "69","status_id": "2","project_name": "Open","clients": {"id": "69","user_id": "1","client_name": "A Arcu Sed Associates",    },        "status": null}] and I have the open statuses retrieved too

Comment: Do you want to `exclude` i.e. `where != 'Open'` ?

Comment: btw I have not included the where('status_id', '!=', '2') as I want to avoid specifying it this way, as the id could be anything really.

Comment: To exclude it, you may use `$q->where('name', '!=', $value);`, updated.

Comment: No i want to retrieve the Open projects. Open is a status name in the statuses table.

Comment: The ->whereHas() method was what I needed to get this to work. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to know that @MiftahAfina :-)

Comment: oh no i have this error, Lazy loading was disabled to detect N+1 problems @TheAlpha

Answer (score 11):

You may try this:

```
Project::with(['clients', 'tasks' => function($q) use($value) {
// Query the name field in status table
    $q->where('status_id', '!=', '2'); 
}])
->whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)
->get();
```

Comment: What if I want to run where clause for 'clients' table also along with this     $q->where('status_id', '!=', '2');

Comment: This answer just copies code directly from the accepted answer, and then makes it less useful.

Answer (score 2):

Now, you can use ***whereRelation***

```
public function getOpenProjects() {

return Project::with(['clients', 'tasks', 'status'])
             ->whereRelation('status', 'name', '!=', '2')        
             ->whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)
             ->get();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you need add condition you could do

```
return Query::with(['department' => function ($query) use ($department) {
           $query->when($department, function ($query) use ($department) {
              $query->whereId($department);
           });
        }, 'category' => function($query) use ($category) {
            $query->when($category, function ($query) use ($category) {
              $query->whereId($category);
           });
        }])->when($activeStatus, function ($query) use ($activeStatus) {
              $activeStatus = (request()->active_status === 'active') ? 1 : 0;
              $query->whereActive($activeStatus);
         })->latest()->paginate($dataPerPage);
```

Or you could do

```
return Query::with('department', 'category')
    ->when($department, function($query) use ($department) {
        $query->whereHas('department', function (Builder $query) use ($department) {
            $query->whereId($department);
        });
    })->when($category, function ($query) use ($category) {
        $query->whereHas('category', function (Builder $query) use ($category) {
            $query->whereId($category);
        });
    })->when($activeStatus, function ($query) use ($activeStatus) {
        $activeStatus = (request()->active_status === 'active') ? 1 : 0;
        $query->whereActive($activeStatus);
    })->latest()->paginate($dataPerPage);
```

Comment: Please do not use images as an answer as this is less accessable.